# Sitecore Identity server logs to Application Insights

Tags: logging, application-insights

**Sitecore.NET 10.1.1 (rev. 005862) in Azure PAAS Scaled**

What I am trying to do:

1. I want to write the logs into the Application Insights for the Sitecore Identity server.

What I have done till:

1. I checked the instrumentation key. It is fine.
2. I checked the daily quota and that is fine.
3. I couldn't find file *Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config* as mentioned [here](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/sitecore-experience-manager/configure-application-insights-post-deployment.html)

Sorry but I am unable to find what I am missing.

Comment: IdentityServer uses the standard logging facilities provided by ASP.NET Core, So I don't think you need to enable anything for logging on any PaaS environment, you already confirm the instrumentation key so you can just confirm the `Role setting` is there under `/Sitecore/Logging/Serilog/Properties`

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need to do is the following.

Download the installation package for `Azure AppService` from the Sitecore Downloads Portal. You are going to copy the files

> Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.config
> Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.Counters
> Sitecore.Cloud.ApplicationInsights.dll

which are only available in the Sitecore Azure AppService installation packages

Read more about to setup with this article.

https://joaoneto.blog/setup-application-insights-sitecore-installation/